# Reduce QMainWindow to QPushbutton

Tags: pyqt5

I'd like to have QMainWindow with a QPushbutton and when I click the QPushbutton,
only the QPushbutton will be visible and when I click the button again,
the QMainWindow will be visible again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question depends on how the QMainWindow and QPushbutton are related, that is, how the QPushbutton was attached to the QMainWindow, and since the OP has not provided any information I will only show a simple demo.

For a widget (for example the QPushButton) to be part of a window then it must be a child of the window or child of a widget that is already in the window, so if you want to show the widget only then you must remove that relationship, and if you want to restore then you must establish kinship.

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.button = QPushButton("Press me", self)
        self.button.setProperty("flag", True)
        self.button.move(100, 100)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handle_clicked)

        self.resize(640, 480)

    def handle_clicked(self):
        flag = self.button.property("flag")
        if flag:
            self.button.setParent(None)
            self.hide()
            self.button.move(self.pos())
            self.button.show()
        else:
            self.button.setParent(self)
            self.button.move(100, 100)
            self.show()

        self.button.setProperty("flag", not flag)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: And is it possible to shift everything to the left and down, when minimized? And the application will be as small as the button?

Comment: And button size should not change, when clicked again (to maximize).

Comment: @xralf 1) I don't understand, if you want to place a window at a specific position then use `move()`, 2) What do you mean by application? You mean a window?

Comment: 2) Yes the Window, but I was using i3 (window manager). Without it it works. But could you achieve the button size don't change yet?

Comment: @xralf With my code it shouldn't be resized, just that any window (the QPushButton is just a window too) has its titlebar and I guess that's what you mean.

Comment: It already works. I don't know why the button was so big, when I clicked to maximize before.

Comment: @xralf I don't understand what you mean by maximize. My code and your question do not indicate anything about maximizing something, please focus on your request, I only discuss the request of the OP that is in the post and possible problems of my solution, nothing more. Bye

Comment: I'm sorry. 'maximize' meant 'as big as the `QMainWindow`'. But it's OK now.